# merge two dataframe based on specific column information

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I am trying to handling dataframe in several ways.
and now I'd like to merge two dataframe based on specific column information and delete rows which is duplicated

Is it possible?
I tried to use Concatenate function but faliled...

for example if I want to merge df1 and df2 into d3 with

condition:

- if c1&c2 information is same, delete duplicated rows(only use df1, even if c3 data between df1 and df2 is different)
- if c1&c2 information is different, use both rows (df1,df2)

before:

```
df1
 c1  c2  c3
0    0   x  {'a':1 ,'b':2} 
1    0   y  {'a':3 ,'b':4}
2    2   z  {'a':5 ,'b':6}

df2
     c1  c2  c3
0    0   x  {'a':11 ,'b':12}
1    0   y  {'a':13 ,'b':14}
2    3   z  {'a':15 ,'b':16}
```

expected result d3:

```
    c1  c2  c3
0    0   x  {'a':1 ,'b':2}
1    0   y  {'a':3 ,'b':4}
2    2   z  {'a':5 ,'b':6}
3    3   z  {'a':15 ,'b':16}
```

enter code here

Comment: How about the merge function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this firstly by determining which rows are only in df2 using `merge` and passing `how='right'` and `indicator=True`, then `concat` this with `df1`:

```
In [125]:
merged = df1.merge(df2, left_on=['c1','c2'], right_on=['c1','c2'], how='right', indicator=True)
merged = merged[merged['_merge']=='right_only']
merged = merged.rename(columns={'c3_y':'c3'})
merged

Out[125]:
   c1 c2 c3_x                c3      _merge
2   3  z  NaN  {'a':15 ,'b':16}  right_only

In [126]:    
combined = pd.concat([df1, merged[df1.columns]])
combined

Out[126]:
   c1 c2                c3
0   0  x    {'a':1 ,'b':2}
1   0  y    {'a':3 ,'b':4}
2   2  z    {'a':5 ,'b':6}
2   3  z  {'a':15 ,'b':16}
```

If we break down the above:

```
In [128]:
merged = df1.merge(df2, left_on=['c1','c2'], right_on=['c1','c2'], how='right', indicator=True)
merged

Out[128]:
   c1 c2            c3_x              c3_y      _merge
0   0  x  {'a':1 ,'b':2}  {'a':11 ,'b':12}        both
1   0  y  {'a':3 ,'b':4}  {'a':13 ,'b':14}        both
2   3  z             NaN  {'a':15 ,'b':16}  right_only

In [129]:
merged = merged[merged['_merge']=='right_only']
merged

Out[129]:
   c1 c2 c3_x              c3_y      _merge
2   3  z  NaN  {'a':15 ,'b':16}  right_only

In [130]:
merged = merged.rename(columns={'c3_y':'c3'})
merged

Out[130]:
   c1 c2 c3_x                c3      _merge
2   3  z  NaN  {'a':15 ,'b':16}  right_only
```